# How to Add Migration in asp.net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

i have create problem on creation of migration, migration is not created
when i created Migration in Package in

**DbInitializer**

```
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(SchoolContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Look for any students.
        if (context.Students.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var students = new Student[]
        {
        new Student{FirstMidName="Carson",LastName="Alexander",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Meredith",LastName="Alonso",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Arturo",LastName="Anand",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Gytis",LastName="Barzdukas",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Yan",LastName="Li",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Peggy",LastName="Justice",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2001-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Laura",LastName="Norman",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Nino",LastName="Olivetto",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")}
        };
        foreach (Student s in students)
        {
            context.Students.Add(s);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

MadeChanges in Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
DbInitializer.Initialize(conetxt);
```

> Package manager consol > Add-Migration FirstMigration and After Completion Update-Database

Problem occured in Update-Database Command

Comment: and the rest of the error message ?

Comment: in ASP.NET Core you do not use Package Manager Console in order do add migrations. You need to use dotnet CLI, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: seems you have a typo in your `Startup.cs` (`conetxt` instead of `context`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With EF Core you now have 2 different command line tools, the **dotnet cli** and the **PM console**. You can check the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/) for further reference.

When using the [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations) migrations can be added with:

> Usage: dotnet ef migrations [options] [command]
>
> Options:
>
> - -h|--help    => Show help information
> - -v|--verbose =>  Enable verbose output
>
> Commands:
>
> - add => Add a new migration
> - list => List the migrations
> - remove => Remove the last migration
> - script => Generate a SQL script from migrations

So in order to add your new *FirstMigration* migration you would run:

```
>dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration
```

The same commands are also available for the [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell):

- If you use Visual Studio 2017, they should already be installed
- If you use Visual Studio 2017, you need to install them with `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Pre`. (Check the section about installing EF Core and EF6 commands side by side on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#using-ef-core-commands-and-ef-6-commands-side-by-side))

In order to add a migration you would then run:

```
>Add-Migration FirstMigration
```